# Replicate whole MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli, replication

Am Using Master master MySql replication
its working fine. Both Server added

```
replicate-do-db=DB1
replicate-do-db=DB2
```

But I have n number of databases and going to increase day by day. It is much difficult to add databases in my.cnf every day. I used

replicate-ignore-db=information_schema in both server but that doesn't work.
Actually what I want how to replicate all database and upcoming databases automatically

Comment: It sounds to me like you are doing something wrong if you are creating databases every day. Can I ask why you are doing this

Comment: remove all `replicate-do-db` (and `replicate-ignore-db`, `binlog-do-db` etc etc) entries, and then everything should replicate automatically.

Comment: what about log-bin,log-error.Shall I remove that too?

Comment: i removed replicate-do-db  (and replicate-ignore-db, binlog-do-db etc etc) But not working

Comment: @RiggsFolly Because for each client .. thats much of tables and data's are there....

Comment: `log-bin` has to stay, that enables the binary logs. Also, you will need to restart the database after making changes to the my.cnf file.

Comment: @IGGt yes I did, Restarted  mysql but no result. is there any command for replicate all data.

Comment: No, if you have no filters in place it will replicate everything by default. run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on each side and look for the `slave_IO_state`, `slave_IO_running`,`slave_SQL_running`,`last_xxx_error` fields for clues as to what is happening.

Comment: @IGGt Slave_IO_Running  Yes , Slave_SQL_Running  No,Slave_IO_State  Waiting for master to send event,Last_Error  Error 'Can't drop database ,Last_Errno  1008

Comment: @IGGt thanks . your suggestions helped me.Now ,Its working fine

Answer (score 0):

if you have no filters in place it will replicate everything by default. run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on each side and look for the `slave_IO_state`, `slave_IO_running`,`slave_SQL_running`,`last_xxx_error` fields for clues as to what is happening. – IGGt

Slave_IO_Running Yes , Slave_SQL_Running No,Slave_IO_State Waiting for master to send event,Last_Error Error 'Can't drop database ,Last_Errno 1008
your suggestions helped me.Now ,Its working fine – Janmabhumi